# Filter rows from the last 15 minutes

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I need to filter from **B to K** IF column A is any time in the last 15 minutes from now **AND** column J says "Yes"

A has the format Hour-Minute-Second, for example "17:20:59". Lets say now is 18:00:00, I want this formula to return all values from 17:45:00 until now.

For now I did this:

```
=FILTER(B:K, A:A=TODAY(),J:J="Yes")
```

I need the same but instead of today, the last 15 minutes.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Now** returns the time whereas **today** does not, just subtract minutes / 1440 because that is how many minutes are in a day:

```
=FILTER(B:K, A:A>=Now()-15/1440+n(whatthefoxsay()),J:J="Yes")
```